# Why doesn't $|uv|\le k$ break the pumping lemma?

Tags: pumping-lemma

Let $N = \{ab^x | x \in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Let the pumping length be $k$. So $ab^k$ belongs to $N$.

Let $u = a, v = b^k, w = \operatorname{empty}$.

Then $|uv|\le k$ does not hold. No other splitting I can find satisfies the requirements and I'm pretty sure this should be the one to work. Why doesn't it?

Comment: Try the splitting $u = a$, $v = b$ and $w = b^{k-1}$?

Comment: Thank you. Had not occurred to me I could do that.

Comment: FYI, the pumping length of your language is 2.